# Mule ESB XPath function sometimes returns ArrayList instead of String for the same value

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

I have this XML as payload:

```
<root>
   <entry>
      <key>mobile_phone</key>
      <value>380929993314</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <key>surname</key>
      <value>Dylan</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <key>name</key>
      <value>Bob</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <key>extension</key>
      <value>208</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <key>mobile_extension</key>
      <value>608</value>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <key>email</key>
      <value>bob@dylan.com</value>
   </entry>
</root>
```

and Mule ESB flow piece for this payload:

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Set Duty Properties" scope="session">
    <add-message-property key="dutyName" value="#[xpath('/root/entry/key[text()=&quot;name&quot;]/../value/text()').getText()]"/>
    <add-message-property key="dutySurname" value="#[xpath('/root/entry/key[text()=&quot;surname&quot;]/../value/text()').getText()]"/>
    <add-message-property key="dutyMobilePhone" value="#[xpath('/root/entry/key[text()=&quot;mobile_phone&quot;]/../value/text()').getText()]"/>
    <add-message-property key="dutyEmail" value="#[xpath('/root/entry/key[text()=&quot;email&quot;]/../value/text()').getText()]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

This code works principally good, but sometimes I get this error on my application:

```
ERROR 2013-11-17 15:42:42,712 [[duty-notifications].supportTicket.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Execution of the expression "xpath('/root/entry/key[text()="mobile_phone"]/../value/text()').getText()" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. [Error: unable to resolve method: java.util.ArrayList.getText() [arglength=0]]
[Near : {... xpath('/root/entry/key[text()= ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1] (org.mvel2.PropertyAccessException)
  org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer:1078 (null)
2. Execution of the expression "xpath('/root/entry/key[text()="mobile_phone"]/../value/text()').getText()" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
  org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:218 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)
3. Execution of the expression "xpath('/root/entry/key[text()="mobile_phone"]/../value/text()').getText()" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)
  org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer:139 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerMessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
[Error: unable to resolve method: java.util.ArrayList.getText() [arglength=0]]
[Near : {... xpath('/root/entry/key[text()= ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
      at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:1078)
      at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:987)
      at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:377)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I.e. for unknow reasons XPath function for dutyMobilePhone sometimes returns ArrayList for "380929993314" instead of String (that is usual).

Please help me. How to prevent this random behavior of XPath function for my case?

Comment: Is it possible that the `value` element of the `mobile_phone` entry contain several text nodes? Have you captured the XML when the error occurs? Also: Mule version?

Comment: Yes, I captured the XML when error occurs. Content of `value` always is _380929993314_. I use Mule 3.5.0.

Comment: Also noticed that after then I changed order of `add-message-property` tags, error disappears for a short time. Mysticism...

Comment: Noticed that then XPath returns ArrayList the value of of `xpath('/root/entry/key[text()=&quot;mobile_phone&quot;]/../value/text()')` is `[org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@17c1e333 [Text: "380"], org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@3a2b3574 [Text: "929993314"]]`

Comment: Another time the value is `[org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@5b2eda6f [Text: "380929993"], org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@6106dc2d [Text: "314"]]`

Comment: As I expected: the parser is free to produce multiple text nodes when you "see" only one string...

Comment: Solved by adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` header in XML. Without this Mule XPath function behaves strangely.

Comment: Have you tried my solution? Readers who can not alter the inbound XML would probably be glad to know if it works or not.

Comment: Your solution unfortunately I have not tried because adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` solved problem for me. If error will occur again, I will keep it in mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your Xpath expressions select the containing elements and get their text content from MEL:

```
value="#[xpath('/root/entry/key[text()=&quot;mobile_phone&quot;]/../value').text]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` header in XML. Without this Mule XPath function behaves strangely.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, except that maybe the strict definition of the XML version or the encoding ends up producing a single text node when some times, several were returned.